# Input filter for switching regulator

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, filter, buck, emc, switching-regulator

I'm trying to create an input filter for a switching regulator for automotive application.

My aim is to make a supply board, where from 24V come out 12V (from the buck) then 10V and 5V (from two LDOs). I use the LMR33630ADDAR from TI that works at 400 kHz and a protection IC, the TPS26400PWPR from TI. I was delving deeper into the input and EMI filter topic and I found that some issues need to be taken into consideration, for example the transfer function, we have to avoid resonance peak, and the output impedance, that have to be lower than the input impedance.
First question now is, how can i calculate the input impedance? Can I consider an indicative value that is always a good reference?

I did some experiments e i want to ask you if this filter can be a good choice. I would have a cutoff frequency close to 4 kHz because some disturbances can come out from the inverter of the car at 16kHz. How can I be sure that the filter also cuts the noise caused by the buck itself?

This is the schematic, lacks to put the filter, that i would to put between the protection IC and the regulator, is it a good choice?

[image]

This is the transfer function of the filter [image]

And this the output impedance (i think that i can calculate in this way, with input short circuited)[image]

Is this a good input filter, In order to attenuate input disturbances and to attenuate oscillation on the supply line due to the switching regulator?