# Input impedance of a buck converter

Tags: current, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, impedance

Is there an approximate formula for calculating the minimum value of the input resistance (or impedance) of a switching regulator? I found several formulas but can't figure out which one to choose. I would need it to understand how to calculate an input filter so that it has an output resistance much smaller than the input resistance of the buck. Otherwise can i calculate through efficiency and power informations?
Thanks

Comment: *input resistance?

Comment: Well which formulas you found and why are you unable to choose between them?

Comment: You might want to look up Middlebrook Criteria.

Comment: @Justme for example  Zin_min = Vin_min^2/(Vout x Iout)  or  Zin_min = Vin^2/(n x Vout x Iout)

Comment: @Gigapel What's the "n" in the formulas? From where did you get them? From wherever they are copied, don't they have text around them to explain when the formulas apply? And those seem just approximations of what kind of DC load resistance the input is. Impedance means also AC, because your regulator could take in 1A for 50% of time to drop 10V into 5V 1A, and 0A in for 50% of time, at some frequency.

Comment: @Justme n is the efficiency

Comment: @Gigapel In that case, both formulas are correct, one of them just assumes efficiency, which is not a letter 'n', to be 100%, i.e. ideal.

Comment: @Justme but this formulas are for the minimum resistance and not for minimum impedance right?

Comment: @Gigapel At DC, they are the same thing, i.e. what value of resistance equals the regulator input as load.

Comment: @yes i know that at DC they are the same thing, but for sizing a filter we need to know the impedance in frequency

Answer (score 8):

I have determined the open-loop input impedance of the buck converter operated in voltage-mode (VM) and current-mode control (CM) in my last [book](https://stairwaypress.com/product/transfer-functions-of-switching-converters/) on transfer functions. When operated in VM, the *incremental* input resistance is positive but it becomes negative in closed-loop operations. On the contrary, in CM, the incremental input resistance is natively negative in open loop.

For a buck converter, you have several options:

1. plot \$Z_{in}\$ in *closed-loop* using the formula I derived in my [APEC 2017](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202017.pdf) presentation. Needless to say, it is quite complex to handle:

[image]

On this graph, you should now superimpose the output impedance magnitude of your EMI filter and check for any overlaps. If there are some, damp the filter to offer a 10-dB margin at least.

2. consider the closed-loop input impedance as a flat magnitude across frequency. In this case, you derive the incremental resistance by \$R_{in}=\frac{V_{in}^2}{P_{in}}\$:

[image]

With this approach, you ignore any notch in the input impedance and need to ensure sufficient margin with the peaking of the EMI filter impedance. I've seen many high-power converters designers successfully applying this method.

3. Use a simulator to plot this closed-loop input impedance in worst-case conditions and that is probably the fastest way to obtain an accurate picture:

[image]

I used one of my free 120+ SIMPLIS [templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) but an averaged model in LTspice or other SPICE-based engine would produce a close plot.

For more information, you can see my [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522058/stability-of-input-filter-in-smps-theoretical-explanation/522069#522069) on SE for instabilities linked to the EMI filter but also some basic guidance on how to design the filter [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/658458/input-filter-to-reduce-conducted-emissions-caused-by-dc-dc-converter/658486#658486).

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification, indeed the approximation of the input resistance as flat could help a lot

Answer (score 2):

For DC it's negative since, for constant output, input voltage and input current have an inverse relationship. That can destabilize an LC filter: you may need to add damping.

At higher frequencies there's no general formula. God is in the details...

Comment: yes, i found application note about damping, but I have to hope that in order for the system to be stable, I can have a minimum input impedance of the buck. And not knowing any of its transfer functions, it all becomes random

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there an approximate formula for calculating the minimum value of
> the input resistance (or impedance) of a switching regulator?*

Within the input supply range that it operates over, you can regard it as a constant power input device (where the power input equals the load power output) plus an offset power that remains roughly constant (representing the power overhead needed to keep the converter functioning).

> *I would need it to understand how to calculate an input filter so that
> it has an output resistance much smaller than the input resistance of
> the buck*

I strongly advise you to check any filter design using a simulator; they are free and accurate. I use micro-cap but, many other use LTspice. A constant power load can be created or, just use your buck converter circuit to get a more accurate result.

Comment: yes, thank you, i'm using LTspice and I am making attempts for a good input filter. I had asked for information in a previous question (  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/698110/input-filter-for-switching-regulator  )  but no one answered me

Comment: @Gigapel if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.